# VBS to write multiple lines in textfile

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that checks for all users and checks for its last login time.
i open a file to write inside the file. However , i seem to have an issue where the it is writing only the last name it checks instead of all the names.

Result in the text should be :

user1
user2
user3
user4

However , this is my current result :

user4

How do i go about this?

I do apologize as i am mainly in C# and VBS is very new to me.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer, objComputer, objUser, FSO, File
Const ForWriting = 2
strComputer = "."
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
objComputer.Filter = Array("user")
For Each objUser In objComputer
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\sgbvx\Desktop\test\test.txt",ForWriting, True)
On Error Resume Next
Wscript.Echo objUser.Name & ", " & objUser.LastLogin
File.WriteLine objUser.Name
File.Write objUser.LastLogin
File.Close
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
On Error GoTo 0
Wscript.Echo objUser.Name & ", "
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next
File.Close
```

Comment: Change `Const ForWriting = 2` to `Const ForAppending = 8` and use that flag in `OpenTextFile`

Comment: Hi Pankaj , i think there is also some issue with the arrangement,  i have done with ForWriting 2. I will post answer below. Thank you Pankaj for the assist. However the problem was in my looping arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently my code has some arrangement issue that created a lot errors.

Here's my answer and an updated code for the above :

```
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer, objComputer, objUser, FSO, File
Const ForWriting = 2
strComputer = "."
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
objComputer.Filter = Array("user")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

//You may change the file name or directory//
Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.txt",ForWriting, True)

//Start of ForEach loop , previously Set FSO and Set File was in this loop//

For Each objUser In objComputer
On Error Resume Next
//Writes Username and LastLogin detail//
File.Write objUser.Name & ", " & objUser.LastLogin
File.WriteLine
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
On Error GoTo 0
//Writes only Username if LastLogin was not detected//
File.Write objUser.Name & ", "
File.WriteLine
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next
File.Close
```